# How can I convert KERAS `MLP` model to `Pythorch` model

Tags: python, pytorch, mlp

I have a `MLP` model using some Project

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding

model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=len(X[0]))
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

But I want to convert this `MLP` model to `Pythorch` model.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

I add this code for generate `data`:

```
def generate_batch_data(x, y, batch_size):
    i, batch = 0, 0
    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, len(x) - batch_size, batch_size), 1):
        x_batch = x[i : i + batch_size]
        y_batch = y[i : i + batch_size]
        yield x_batch, y_batch
    if i + batch_size < len(x):
        yield x[i + batch_size :], y[i + batch_size :]
    if batch == 0:
        yield x, y
```

and this code:

```
epochs = 10
batch_size = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}')
   
    for x_train, y_train in generate_batch_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
        y_hat = model(x_train)
        loss = criterion(y_hat, y_train)
        acc = (y_hat.argmax(1) == y).float().mean()

        print(f'loss: {loss}, accuracy: {acc}')
```

This time I take a this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-7ffa61cb7f34> in <module>()
      5 
      6     for x_train, y_train in generate_batch_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
----> 7         y_hat = model(x_train)
      8         loss = criterion(y_hat, y_train)
      9         acc = (y_hat.argmax(1) == y).float().mean()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1850         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1851         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1852     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1853 
   1854 

RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar type Long; but got torch.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)
```

I added here `torch.LongTensor`:

```
def tokenize_and_pad_text(df, max_seq):
  tokenized_text = tokenize_text(df, max_seq)
  padded_text = pad_text(tokenized_text, max_seq)
  return torch.LongTensor(padded_text)

train_indices = tokenize_and_pad_text(df_train, max_seq)

x_train = bert_model(train_indices)[0]
```

And change here:

`y_hat = model(x_train.long())`

But this time it gives this errors:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-9ad38a8c062a> in <module>()
      5 
      6     for x_train, y_train in generate_batch_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
----> 7         y_hat = model(x_train.long())
      8         loss = criterion(y_hat, y_train)
      9         acc = (y_hat.argmax(1) == y).float().mean()

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1850         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1851         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1852     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1853 
   1854 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

And model is like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=148, embedding_dim=768),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear((768*148), 148),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(148, 3))

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

Normally using `dataframe context column` like this:

```
def tokenize_text(df, max_seq):
  return[
         tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True)[:max_seq] for text in df.context.values
  ]

def pad_text(tokenized_text, max_seq):
  return np.array([el + [0] * (max_seq - len(el)) for el in tokenized_text])
```

and after comments: I take `len(df.context)` is `148` and update`num_embeddings` as 148. I still keep getting `the same error`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the model definition with loss function and optimizer:

```
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_size, embedding_dim=50),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(50*len(X[0]), 100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(100, 3))

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

And here is a rough outline of a training loop:

```
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}')

    for x, y in data:
        y_hat = model(x)
        loss = criterion(y_hat, y)
        acc = (y_hat.argmax(1) == y).float().mean()

        print(f'loss: {loss}, accuracy: {acc}')
```

Assuming `data` contains `(x, y)` training points, and `y` has a single dimension containing the ground truth class indices.

---

Additional comments:

- PyTorch uses dynamic model definition, it cannot infer the output sizes of the previous layers. In Keras, you need to provide `input_length` on the first layer. Notice `nn.Linear(50*len(X[0]), 100)` (in *Pytorch*) vs `Dense(100)` (in *Keras*).
- No need for a [`nn.Softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html#torch.nn.Softmax) when using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) (it already used [`nn.LogSoftmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LogSoftmax.html))
- For reference: [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html#torch.nn.Sequential), [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html#torch.nn.Linear), [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html#torch.nn.Flatten), and [`nn.Embedding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html#torch.nn.Embedding).

Comment: I take an error like this `nn.ReLU(),
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent` <br/> and y is a tensor, `torch.Size([10, 3])`. <br/>Thans a lot.

Comment: And another matter in all the examples on the internet, the `class` structure was used and `def forward` was used. What's that?

Comment: That's just an indentation error you should be able to fix it. As for the class structure, you can wrap your model definition in a class inheriting from `nn.Module`. See [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_module.html) page for more details

Comment: You should cast `x_train` to a `torch.LongTensor` with `model(x_train.long())`

Comment: I tried to do as you said. I tried to do as you said. But this time I got the error `index out of range in self`. I updated the question and added it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to look at all codes, you can find the colab link [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xG2Wsp8J-0DKhb5VI1n7uUeSo_YzMLHY?usp=sharing). Thanks a lot again.

Comment: There must be a problem with your input shape, can you print `x_train.shape`?

Comment: Sure, `x_train` shape is `torch.Size([1, 100, 768])` and x_train[0] shape is `torch.Size([100, 768])`.

Comment: Your `nn.Embedding` seems too small, you have set `num_embeddings` to 100. Instead, it should equal your vocabulary size.

Comment: Actually I updated your first answer. And I added the `model part` to the question again

Comment: `num_embeddings` still at *100*

Comment: I updated the problem with the relevant sections. I use `df.contexts` for embedding and the length is `148`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your vocabulary size is not the length it's the number of unique inputs

Comment: Ok, I learns number of unique inputsi using this code `tokenizer.num_words` on `Glove`, but ı don't 't know on `BERT`